# JPA Named query returns partial Result sporadically

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0, eclipselink, named-query

I have a table PhoneModels

ID, Name , Vendor

1, iphone, Apple

2, Xperia, Sony Erricson

3, Razor, Motorola

i have a corresponding Entity
class PhoneModel implements Serializable {

```
@Id  
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)   
@Column(nullable = false)   
private Long id;   

@Column(nullable = false)   
private String phoneName;   

@Column(nullable = false)   
private String vendor;
```

i have a corresponding Entity 
class PhoneModel implements Serializable {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String phoneName;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String vendor;
```

and a corresponding named query

@NamedQuery(name = "phones.findAll", query = "select o from PhoneModels o"),

but weirdly **sometimes** the result of the above NamedQuery returns me partial result

ID, Name , Vendor

1, <---------------------------missing name and vendor

2, Xperia, Sony Erricson

3, Razor, Motorola

**most importantly it is SPORADIC once in 1000 times and it goes of without any change in code or server**

this is the version we use 
EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635

Comment: 1. During the read of the entities, does your or some other application change the underlying table? 2. Does this also happen, when you are using a regular JPQL query instead of a named query? 3. You are using a pretty old eclipselink version. Try upgrading to a newer release.